# Search Core Results - what is generating the link to update my profile?

Tags: web-part, people-picker, content-search-web-part, people-search

[image: Search Results]

I have a SharePoint 2010 "Search Core Results" web part on each departmental site for my company to show the employees in that department. Each web part appears to be identical, with only the "Fixed Keyword Query" different to match the department, such as the following examples.

```
Department:"Internal Audit"
Department:"Human Resources"
```

These properly bring back all employees in the department based on AD information. However, in only ONE department, the users see an additional section underneath their photo with links to update their profile. This causes users with lower screen resolutions to have other content on the page compressed. No one uses the profile section, so optimally, I'd like to completely remove that.

What could be causing only one department to be seeing that profile section? How can I completely remove this profile section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called the "Self Search" profile result. In people search if you find yourself the result shows your query statistics and a link to your profile. You can comment this out in the Search Result XSL.

Comment: Perfect! I edited the web part. Under "Display Properties" I clicked "XSL Editor". I then commented out the DIVs "SelfSrchHeading", "SelfSrchFreq", "SelfSrchTerms" and "Clear2".